# Mongo: Sort objects in a collection with a timestamp in a different collection

Tags: mongodb

I have some collection `A` with `_id, content, timestamp` as fields and some collection `B` with `A_id, _id, content, timestamp` as fields. `A_id` refers to some object in `A`.

I want to sort the objects in `A` based on their latest timestamps in `B`.

I can get it to work by re architecting my db design (e.g. storing a `latest_B_timestamp` in `A`) BUT is there a simple way to do this directly with Mongo?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is any good way to do that with mongo. Your current solution seems ok and natural in mongo. Duplication is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No.

MongoDB has no joins, so if 2 collections have related data, they should be worked in the application layer.